# Get to Data in Clipboard from Selenium Client

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver

I want to access some data which is copied to the clipboard on a website when you click a button (Jscript)
I use Remotewebdriver (ChromeDriver) to control the testcase but couldn't find out how to access this information.

Anybody knows how?

If possible with c# but a java solution may also work.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could not figure out how to do this so my way was to render a textarea with Jquery and CTRL+V the text into that box just to then get the value back with webdriver. Not pretty but it works

```
var javaScript = "$( \".d-modal-footer\").html('<div><textarea id=errormessagecopy maxlength=\"5000\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"40\"></textarea></div>');";

WebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript(javaScript);
var errormessagecopy = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("errormessagecopy"));

new Actions(WebDriver).MoveToElement(errormessagecopy).Click().KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).SendKeys("v").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).Perform();

var errorText = WebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("return $(\"#errormessagecopy\").val();");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API but as described in the documentation to read the value from it you need to grant permission in the browser. After you have permission simply execute js script on-page from selenium and get that value.