# C# Selenium/ChromeDriver allow clipboard permission

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I allow clipboard permission in Selenium using C#?
[Clipboard permission popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkB7q.png)
I spend a lot of time to figure out this question but did not find the answer

I tried to do something like this:

```js
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.clipboard_controls_mode", 1);
```

But it does not work

[Accept Clipboard permission request in chrome using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107578/accept-clipboard-permission-request-in-chrome-using-selenium) Here exists solution but I don't know how to implement it on C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706558/get-to-data-in-clipboard-from-selenium-client

Answer (score 0):

try below version for C#, should solve your problem

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var clipboardException = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  {"[*.]myurl.com,*", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
      {"last_modified", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}, 
      {"setting", 1}
    }
  }
};          
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard", clipboardException);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.